# Cambridge Mathematical Tripos Question - 1871

Tags: probability, classical-mechanics

This is a question from the Cambridge Mathematical Tripos in 1871, Scanned copy added at the end of the post.

> A ship $A$ sees another ship 
>   $B$ whose course is not known. Given that they have the same speed, prove that chance of them coming within a distance $d$ of each other is always $\frac{2sin^{-1}(\frac{d}{a})}{\pi}$ no matter the course of $A$, provided that it's inclination to $AB$ is not greater than $cos^{-1}(\frac{d}{a})$where $AB=a$

This is a summary of my method so far:

First I constructed a vector triangle $ABC$ where $C$ was the intersection of the courses of $A$ and $B$. In this triangle I denoted the angle between $A$ and $AB$ as $\theta$ and $B$ and $AB$ as $\phi$.

I then used trigonometry to get an expression for $d$ which I subsequently differentiated with respect to time and set as a minimum so I could get $t=\frac{b+c}{2v}$ where $v$ is the velocity of the ships.

Using this I got $d=acos(\frac{\theta + \phi}{2})$ which implies $\phi=2cos^{-1}(\frac{d}{a})-\theta$

Could someone help me proceed and  post a solution themselves if they have a better method?

It would also be helpful if you could point out if this is possible to complete having only high school maths knowledge.

[image: Scan of the question]

Comment: No one is going to navigate (pun intended) the scrawl of your notes. Much better to give a typed up summary of your method so far.

Comment: I've edited my question for the better now, I hope. As a side note, do you know why images' quality are severely reduced when attached to questions?

Comment: Can I ask you to double check the form of the answer? I have a solution for probability $\displaystyle \frac{\arcsin(d/a)}{\pi}$; I'm missing the factor of $2$. With probability greater than $1/2$ it's my fault. ;-) But just in case...

Comment: I can confirm that factor of 2 is there. I've added a scanned copy of the question into my original post.

Comment: I haven't had time to look at this properly. But I'll try tomorrow, if someone else doesn't jump in first. I like this problem.

Comment: @SimonS Would you mind posting your answer if you have reached one?

Comment: I still only have an incomplete answer, sorry.

Comment: @SimonS Did you approach this problem in a similar way as I did in my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just learned about double integrals and their application in probability so I think I can finish off the problem now.

Continuing from where I got to, the chance would be:

$$\frac{\int^{cos^{-1}(\frac da)}_{-cos^{-1}(\frac da)} \int^{2\pi - \phi}_{\phi} \; d\theta d\phi}{\int^{cos^{-1}(\frac da)}_{-cos^{-1}(\frac da)} \int^{2\pi}_{0} \; d\theta d\phi} $$

Which is equal to:

$$\frac{2\int^{cos^{-1}(\frac da)}_{-cos^{-1}(\frac da)}(\pi - \phi) \; d\theta}{4\pi cos^{-1}(\frac da)}$$

This works out to:

$$\frac{\pi - 2cos^{-1}(\frac da)}{\pi}=\frac{2sin^{-1}(\frac da)}{\pi}$$

I think this is right, would anyone mind double checking or even better suggesting a different method if one exists?